# onWorkflowItemChanged triggered when attachment added through web service

Tags: list, workflow, web-services

A WCF Service hosted outside of SP will consume another external service to retrieve information. Then, the WCF will add/edit an item to a SharePoint List using COM, and add the attachment to the item with Lists.asmx

The Problem is the onWorkflowItemChanged is triggered more than once because the WCF Service call the AddAttachment() method multiple times.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming this is a custom workflow built in Visual Studio. How about you put the onWorkflowItemChanged activity in a loop that checks for a particular field value which is set by the WCF service once it has completed the update.